# regarding generating a unique value for a set of numbers and regenerating the set of values when we pass back the same unique value

Tags: java, php, sql, unix, ksh

I need to write a function (logic) so that for a set say A{1,2,3,4,5} i generate a unique value .
and when i pass back the same value back to the function it should return me the set of values present in the set .
For example the unique value generated is say '5' then when i pass 5 as input to the function it should give me all the values of set A i.e 1,2,3,4,5.

So i need to know if it can be achieved using any statistical approach like mean median mode etc something like that .

Comment: Sounds like you need a injective & invertible map/transformation. Since language doesn't matter, it's rather a question for [Math](http://math.stackexchange.com/) or similar

Comment: you can help me out in the language you are comfortable with @kingkero

Comment: You misunderstood. We're not here to do your homework and this question lacks prior effort and showed no attempts to solve this yourself. Unless you do (and I hope I gave you some good buzzwords in my first comment), I won't be answering at all

Comment: i tried by adding all the random numbers by some value and then subtracting the value based on the number of elements in the set so as to retrieve the elements in reverse order . Will this approach work or not is my question for a set with fixed no of values

Comment: I was interested in this myself so I thought a little about it. It is quite easy actually - what you can do is take each `n` of your set and calculate `2^n` - sum them up and you get a binary number that has 1's at each position an original number was (at 0's otherwise) - as [this script does](http://codepad.org/8JmBiMR1), if you have not so small input, you might need to improve it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

`$valSet = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
    $authNum = 5;
    if($authNum == $someInputByUser)
    {
        print $varSet;
    }`

Is this what you mean?

Comment: no the value which you hard coded as 5 should be generated from the array you used and it should be unique for a particular set so that if i pass the value to the function it will return the elements

Comment: Then simply do `$authNum = $valSet[array_rand($valSet)];` @venkat